# Display custom registered posts in the custom query new WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type

I'm building a custom plugin for WordPress to display some custom posts.
So far so good, it worked (I had to re-save the permalinks), and now I'm able to see it in my archive page and, since I added the slug in the array for the register_post_type function, I can see them adding the slug in the url (for example: mywebsite.com/coolposts:

```
'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'coolposts' ),
```

So far so good but I have a problem and I don't know how to solve it.

I want to display my custom posts "coolposts" in my custom query:

```
$the_query = new WP_Query('orderby=title&order=asc&posts_per_page=50'); 
while ($the_query->have_posts()) :
$the_query->the_post();

if ((($the_query->current_post+1) % 3 == 0) && ($the_query->current_post+1 !== count($the_query->posts))):
echo "</div><div class='row'>";

endif;
endwhile;
```

Because, for some reason, my custom posts are excluded from the main query.

Am I doing something wrong?

Just to be clear, I don't want to display ONLY my customs posts, I want to display all of my posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you registered custom post type with the name `coolposts` when registered with `register_post_type` function. If so then just add another param `post_type=coolposts`. To avoid unexpected situation you can add one more param `post_status=publish`, this param will ensure only published posts are displayed.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query('orderby=title&order=asc&posts_per_page=50&post_type=coolposts');
```

Comment: Actually I developed another approach, it is probably more elegant:

what about:

$args = array(
   'post_type' => array( 'post', 'coolposts' ),
   'orderby' => 'title',
   'order'  => 'asc',
   'posts_per_page' => 30
  );
  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

Comment: With post_type=coolposts you're gonna display only the coolposts posts

Comment: Yeah, your latest approach is definitely more elegant. And thanks learned a new stuff. I didn't know that post_type supports an array of post types.